# iphone iOS memoryWarning handle for navigationController and ALAssetlibrary

Tags: iphone, ios, memory

I do resizing for FullReoslutionImage, so it may introduce memorywarning from iOS. 
   When I recieved memorywarning, it sometimes unload my ALassetlibrary for album, and it introduce crash when users choose image. 
   How could I prevent this kind of problem, how to unload my other resources and other viewController?
   On other hand, when viewcontroller is unloaded, when I go back to this view , it seems introduce crash. How to prevent it ?
   Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

I found it was reduced much when I use 3rd party JPEG decode library to decode&resize it under 2048x2048 UIImage. So the memory wanring happen so often may be caused by creating UIImage larger than 2Kx2K.
 Hope this helps.